# Oracle errors for scripts

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help I keep on getting this error on my coding not sure what I have done wrong. Please help.

```
CREATE TABLE VOLUNTEER (    VOL_ID  VARCHAR2 (8) NOT NULL,  FNAME   ORA- 00907: missing right parenthesis   - 2 0.01    

CREATE TABLE STUDENT (  Vol_id  VARCHAR2 (8) NOT NULL,  Student ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
```

These are my codes:

```
CREATE TABLE VOLUNTEER (
  VOL_ID    VARCHAR2 (8) NOT NULL,
  FULLNAME  VARCHAR2 (14)NOT NULL,
  SURNAME   VARCHAR2 (14) NOT NULL,
  ADDRESS   VARCHAR2 (13) NOT NULL,
  DOB    DATE,
  PHONE NUMBER CHAR (8) NOT NULL,
  EMAIL VARCHAR2 (10) NOT NULL,
  PASSPORT NUMBER   VARCHAR2 (10) NOT NULL,
  NATIONALITY   VARCHAR2 (10) NOT NULL,
  PASSPORT EXPIRY   DATE,
  GENDER    VARCHAR2 (10) NOT NULL,
  REGISTERED DISABLED   VARCHAR2 (10) NOT NULL,
  ETHNICITY VARCHAR2 (14) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk1_Vol_id VARCHAR2 (8) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_Vol PRIMARY KEY (Vol_id));

CREATE TABLE STUDENT (
  Vol_id    VARCHAR2 (8) NOT NULL,
  Student_id    VARCHAR2 (8) NOT NULL,
  Course    VARCHAR2 (8) NOT NULL,
  Studyyear DATE,
  CONSTRAINT PK_STUDENTS PRIMARY KEY (Vol_id),
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first query check this line

```
PHONE       NUMBER CHAR (8) NOT NULL,
```

this might be the correct as per your code

```
PHONE_NUMBER CHAR (8) NOT NULL,
```

Working second query. Check the systax.

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT   (
  Vol_id     VARCHAR2 (8) NOT NULL,
  Student_id VARCHAR2 (8) NOT NULL,
  Course     VARCHAR2 (8) NOT NULL,
  Studyyear DATE,
  CONSTRAINT PK_STUDENTS PRIMARY KEY (Vol_id) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Some errors:

- Change `PASSPORT NUMBER` to `PASSPORT_NUMBER` (same for phone number, passport expiry and registered disabled).
- You do not need a `NOT NULL` constraint on the `PRIMARY KEY`.
- It is good practice to name your constaints.
- Students is missing its closing bracket.

Like this:

```
CREATE TABLE VOLUNTEER (
  VOL_ID              VARCHAR2(8)  CONSTRAINT VOLUNTEER__VI__PK PRIMARY KEY,
  FULLNAME            VARCHAR2(14) CONSTRAINT VOLUNTEER__F__NN  NOT NULL,
  SURNAME             VARCHAR2(14) CONSTRAINT VOLUNTEER__S__NN  NOT NULL,
  ADDRESS             VARCHAR2(13) CONSTRAINT VOLUNTEER__AD__NN NOT NULL,
  DOB                 DATE,
  PHONE_NUMBER        CHAR(8)      CONSTRAINT VOLUNTEER__PH__NN NOT NULL,
  EMAIL               VARCHAR2(10) CONSTRAINT VOLUNTEER__EM__NN NOT NULL,
  PASSPORT_NUMBER     VARCHAR2(10) CONSTRAINT VOLUNTEER__PN__NN NOT NULL,
  NATIONALITY         VARCHAR2(10) CONSTRAINT VOLUNTEER__N__NN  NOT NULL,
  PASSPORT_EXPIRY     DATE,
  GENDER              VARCHAR2(10) CONSTRAINT VOLUNTEER__G__NN  NOT NULL,
  REGISTERED_DISABLED VARCHAR2(10) CONSTRAINT VOLUNTEER__RD__NN NOT NULL,
  ETHNICITY           VARCHAR2(14) CONSTRAINT VOLUNTEER__E__NN  NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE STUDENT (
  Vol_id     VARCHAR2(8) CONSTRAINT STUDENT__VI__PK PRIMARY KEY,
  Student_id VARCHAR2(8) CONSTRAINT STUDENT__SI__NN NOT NULL,
  Course     VARCHAR2(8) CONSTRAINT STUDENT__C__NN  NOT NULL,
  Study_year DATE
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Along with the other issues mentioned, the definition you give for `CONSTRAINT fk1_Vol_id` is not valid. You have it as

```
CONSTRAINT fk1_Vol_id VARCHAR2 (8) NOT NULL
```

It should be something along the lines of

```
CONSTRAINT fk1_Vol_id FOREIGN KEY (VOL_ID) REFERENCES STUDENT(VOL_ID)
```

However, this doesn't seem to make a lot of sense as you have `VOL_ID` as the primary key on both `STUDENT` and `VOLUNTEER`. Perhaps it would be better to have `STUDENT_ID` serve as the primary key on `STUDENT`, and have `STUDENT.VOL_ID` refer back to the `VOLUNTEER` table. Thus, what might work better would be:

```
CREATE TABLE VOLUNTEER (
  VOL_ID               VARCHAR2 (8)
    CONSTRAINT PK_VOLUNTEER
      PRIMARY KEY
        USING INDEX,
  FULLNAME             VARCHAR2 (14) NOT NULL,
  SURNAME              VARCHAR2 (14) NOT NULL,
  ADDRESS              VARCHAR2 (13) NOT NULL,
  DOB                  DATE,
  PHONE_NUMBER         CHAR (8) NOT NULL,
  EMAIL                VARCHAR2 (10) NOT NULL,
  PASSPORT_NUMBER      VARCHAR2 (10) NOT NULL,
  NATIONALITY          VARCHAR2 (10) NOT NULL,
  PASSPORT_EXPIRY      DATE,
  GENDER               VARCHAR2 (10) NOT NULL,
  REGISTERED_DISABLED  VARCHAR2 (10) NOT NULL,
  ETHNICITY            VARCHAR2 (14) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE STUDENT (
  STUDENT_ID           VARCHAR2 (8)
    CONSTRAINT PK_STUDENTS
      PRIMARY KEY
        USING INDEX,
  VOL_ID               VARCHAR2 (8) NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT STUDENT_FK1
      REFERENCES VOLUNTEER (VOL_ID),
  COURSE               VARCHAR2 (8) NOT NULL,
  STUDYYEAR            DATE);
```

Best of luck.